# rollup output as string into JSON file instead of directly as a JS file

Tags: rollup, rollupjs

```
   export default {
      input: 'src/main.sidebar.ts',
      output: {
        sourcemap: false,
        format: 'iife',
        name: 'sidebar',
        file: 'public/build/sidebar.json'
      },
```

I have a mini swelte app as a sidebar.

The rollup config above pipes the compiled output as is into a .json file.

How can I write (pardon the noobness of rollup here) a "middleware" that will grab the output and wrap into a simple json object?

I need to transport this JS code in a JSON payload.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a plugin, those have several hooks you can define, in particular the [generateBundle](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#generatebundle) one will allow you to inspect the generated bundle. Then using [this.emitFile](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#thisemitfileemittedfile-emittedchunk--emittedasset--string) plugin context function you can actually output your JSON. Here is an example

```js
plugins: [
    {
        name: 'whatever',
        generateBundle(outputOptions, bundle) {
            const entry = Object.values(bundle).find((chunk) => chunk.isEntry);
            this.emitFile({
               type: 'asset',
               fileName: 'entry.json',
               source: JSON.stringify(entry.code) 
            });
        }
    }
]
```